"constexpr" and std::to_string in C++ 20
I have the following declaration -
constexpr unsigned int compileYear = (__DATE__[7] - '0') * 1000 + (__DATE__[8] - '0') * 100 + (__DATE__[9] - '0') * 10 + (__DATE__[10] - '0');

Using Visual Studio 2022 and C++ 20, this function cannot compile:
constexpr std::string get_compilation_year()
{
    return std::to_string(compileYear); // cannot result in a constant expression 
}

And for some reason, adding an empty string to it, makes it compile successfully:
constexpr std::string get_compilation_year()
{
    return std::to_string(compileYear) + ""; // OK, it works 
}

I want to understand the reason for that behavior of the compiler.

std::to_string(int) isn't constexpr so even if it compiles, I would be surprised if you could actually initialize a constexpr variable by calling get_compilation_year().

What about constexpr std::string get_compilation_year() { return {__DATE__[7], __DATE__[8], __DATE__[9], __DATE__[10]}; } instead? Even return {__DATE__ + 7, __DATE__ + 7 + 4}; would be an option but clang doesn't like that.

I doubt this could be the minimal reproducible sample.

static constexpr std::string_view compilation_year{&(__DATE__)[0] + 7, 4}; will do

std::to_string(int) is not constexpr so you will not be able to initialize a constexpr variable via a call to get_compilation_year() even if it compiles in its current state.
You could use one of the constexpr std::string constructors instead:
template< class InputIt >
constexpr std::string(InputIt first, InputIt last,
                      const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

or
constexpr std::string(std::initializer_list<char> ilist,
                      const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

Currently, only the one that takes an std::initializer_list<char> works in this context in MSVC, gcc and clang. Clang doesn't like the iterator version (yet).
So, a (somewhat) portable C++20 version could look like this:
constexpr std::string get_compilation_year() {
    return {__DATE__[7], __DATE__[8], __DATE__[9], __DATE__[10]};
}

Or as suggested by Pepijn Kramer, make it a std::string_view instead:
constexpr std::string_view get_compilation_year() {
    return {__DATE__ + 7, 4};
}

The somewhat portable version works as long as there's no allocation made by the constructor. For a longer text including the current year, you could initialize a std::array and create a std::string_view over it:
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

constinit auto copyright_data = [] {
    auto& beg = "Copyright (C) XXXXX 1986 - ";
    return [&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return std::array{beg[I]..., __DATE__[7], __DATE__[8], __DATE__[9],
                          __DATE__[10]};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof(beg) - 1>{});
}();

constexpr std::string_view copyright_text{copyright_data.begin(),
                                          copyright_data.end()};

Demo

Thank you for this answer, but I still don't understand why adding an empty string "" makes it compile and work correctly.

@ChrisNikolaev My only guess is that the operator + usage tricks MSVC somehow so that it doesn't understand what's going on. Have you tried initializing a constexpr variable by using the function? It does not work in my version of MSVC.

Yes, in another source file, I have: auto copyright_text = "Copyright (C) XXXXX 1986 - " + get_compilation_year();

@ChrisNikolaev Try making that constexpr

You're right. Adding constexpr doens't work. So basically, it gets compiled because MSVC is tricked, and nothing in the C++ standard explains that strange behavior that concatenating the value and an empty string makes any difference. Thank you!

@ChrisNikolaev You're welcome! Yes, that's at least what I believe is going on inside MSVC. The other compilers refuses the + "" version as well as the one without it.
